# Is it possible to delete couple of activities from activity stack

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

There are multiple activities that can trigger `registration activity` in my app.

Registration activity consists of `5 activities` activities. Now once registration is completed I want to take the user to `ProfilePageActivity`, and when the user presses back button from `ProfilePageActivity`, I want to take the user to the activity they were in when they called `RegistrationActivity`

If I use these;

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

they will remove the entire stack, and when the user presses the back button it will exit the application.

I want to know if there is any way I can define the range of activities to be deleted from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TaskStackBuilder` ,try this

```
TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                            .addNextIntent(mainActivityIntent())
                            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(myTripActivityIntent())
                            .startActivities();
```

And function is

```
private Intent mainActivityIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        return intent;
    }

    private Intent myTripActivityIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyTripActivity.class);
        return intent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use `Fragment` in your `RegisterActivity`.

if you still want to do like this, you should use `startActivityforResult`. when last activity has finish button click, finish activity with `RESULT_OK`. now in 4th activity check result, if it `RESULT_OK` then do same process untill. it comes to first activity that is `RegisterActivity`. now here if you get `RESULT_OK` then call your `ProfilePageActivity`.